# Packing an IEEE-754 16-bit float to a 16-bit unsigned integer while preserving order

Tags: floating-point, type-conversion, comparison, endianness, ieee-754

I have an IEEE-754 16-bit float that I'd like to losslessly pack as a 16-bit unsigned integer. The easiest way of course is to just pack its bytes and then unpack it, but the snag is that I need to compare the 16-bit integers afterwards (ie greater than, less than, etc) in my program. So I'm looking for an isomorphism between f16 and u16 that preserves order. Could anyone suggest an algorithm that does this? Thanks!

Comment: I have allowed myself to adjust the tags you have used for the question, feel free to undo if that was not according to your intention. Could you provide an example where you are running into issues? Endianness is mostly handled by the lower level implementation, unless you are exchanging raw data between different architectures.

Comment: Does the integer representation absolutely have to be unsigned?  IEE754 seems to have the same basic structure as the longer standard float sizes, which have the property that you can simply consider the bits to be a signed integer and get proper comparison behavior.  (Well, except for NaNs, but there's no possible int values that behave like a NaN.)

Comment: It does need to be unsigned, unfortunately. I can try to refactor the algorithm, but the easiest way given the current code base is to work with unsigneds. One convenient thing is that my float will always be positive, so perhaps by dropping the sign bit an f16 could be compared in the same manner?

Comment: The existing representation is very, very close.  I think you just need to (a) if the MSbit is 0, leave it alone and (b) if the MSbit is 1, set the remaining 15 bits to 32768 - the remaining bits.  (Or as a one-liner, `(x & 0x8000) ? (0x8000 | (0x8000 - (x & 0x7fff))) : x`.)

Comment: I'll try it out! Would the above be an isomorphism, or is it one way? I'd assume the same conversion works both ways based on how you're describing it.

Comment: Yes, it should work both ways (just like [rot13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) :-) ).

Comment: But I was off by one.  Subtract from 32767, or `0x7fff`.

Comment: And if your numbers are always positive, you can skip all that!  You only need to do any of that fussing in order to get the negatives to compare properly as (signed) integers.  (To get them to compare properly as unsigneds would take a bit more work, namely toggling the `0x8000` bit.  I overlooked this at first.  Final answer `(x & 0x8000) ? 0x7fff - (x & 0x7fff) : 0x80000 | x`.  And, still one bug: this compares `+0 > -0`, when they should compare equal.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To maintain `<, ==, >` of a float16 with integer math, treat the data as if it was a *signed* integer encodes using sign-magnitude.

Do this with `float` and `(u)int32_t` to get the code right (as `float16_t` not well available to all) and then adjust for 16-bit.

Negate negative values to positive and set the MSBit for positive ones.

Make certain +0.0 and -0.0 convert to the same value.

```
// Assumes same endian for FP and integers
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Assumes same endian for FP and integers
unsigned float_to_sequence(float f) {
  union {
    float f;
    int32_t i;
    uint32_t u;
  } x = {.f = f};
  if (x.i < 0) {
    x.u = -x.u;
  } else {
    x.u |= 0x80000000;
  }
  return x.u;
}
```

Test

```
void test(float f) {
  printf("%+-20a %+-18.9e ", f, f);
  printf("0x%08X\n", float_to_sequence(f));
}

int main(void) {
  float f[] = {-INFINITY, -FLT_MAX, -1.0, -FLT_TRUE_MIN, -0.0, //
      0.0, FLT_TRUE_MIN, 1.0, FLT_MAX, INFINITY};
  size_t n = sizeof f / sizeof f[0];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    test(f[i]);
  }
}
```

Output

```
-inf                 -inf               0x00800000
-0x1.fffffep+127     -3.402823466e+38   0x00800001
-0x1p+0              -1.000000000e+00   0x40800000
-0x1p-149            -1.401298464e-45   0x7FFFFFFF
-0x0p+0              -0.000000000e+00   0x80000000
+0x0p+0              +0.000000000e+00   0x80000000
+0x1p-149            +1.401298464e-45   0x80000001
+0x1p+0              +1.000000000e+00   0xBF800000
+0x1.fffffep+127     +3.402823466e+38   0xFF7FFFFF
+inf                 +inf               0xFF800000
```

The conversion is one-one except for +0.0 and -0.0 both convert to the same value - as it should.

For a 16-bit one liner: `uint16_t y = (x & 0x8000) ? -x : (x | 0x8000);`